# TextKit drawing excess at top of graphics context

Tags: ios, ios7, textkit

I'm drawing directly into a graphics context by constructing the iOS 7 Text Kit "stack" of classes myself and asking for the glyphs to be drawn. This is my custom UIView subclass's `drawRect:` implementation:

```
NSLayoutManager* lm = [NSLayoutManager new];
NSTextStorage* ts = 
    [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithAttributedString:self.attributedText];
[ts addLayoutManager:lm];
NSTextContainer* tc =
    [[NSTextContainer alloc]
        initWithSize:rect.size];
[lm addTextContainer:tc];
tc.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
NSRange r = NSMakeRange(0,lm.numberOfGlyphs);
[lm drawBackgroundForGlyphRange:r atPoint:CGPointMake(0,10)];
[lm drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:r atPoint:CGPointMake(0,10)];
```

It seems innocent enough, but an odd thing is happening: the excess text (i.e. too much text for the size of the text container) is being drawn as an extra line across the top of the graphics context:

[image]

I can skirt the issue by limiting the range of drawn glyphs to those that fit into the text container:

```
NSRange r = [lm glyphRangeForTextContainer:tc];
```

But I feel I shouldn't have to do that. And I've also seen this problem in a UITextView (where I'm not the one issuing the drawing calls), so I'm a little worried that this is just a bug in iOS 7's TextKit.

Comment: Does this behavior change at all if you manipulate the point you're passing to `-drawGlyphsForGlyphRange:atPoint:`? This point is supposed to be the origin of the text container ("The position of the text container in the coordinate system of the currently focused view" to be specific). From your code it's unclear if it is correct or not.

Comment: @BenLachman No, I moved the drawing down to `(0,10)` to show extra line at the top, but even if you move up to `(0,0)` you can see the bottom of the extra line - I moved it down just to make it clearer what was happening. Besides, the point in question is arbitrary; where the text container (which is just an abstraction of a rectangle) is supposed to be in the real world (e.g. a graphics context) is entirely up to you.

Comment: In that case, I'd say this is either a documentation omission (e.g. "never tell a container to draw more glyphs than returned by `-glyphRangeForTextContainer:`") or simply a missed range check in the underlying system drawing code. My experience of the TextKit docs are that they're still a bit sparse in places.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report to Apple, so if they think it's behaving correctly they can just say so. :) TextKit is actually very well documented over on OS X, where it has been around for a long time, so I'm wondering whether the same thing would happen there.

Comment: Mac is where I first used TextKit as well. And you're right, checking it there would be a good test of whether it's likely a bug or not.